# Angular 8 - render one of the ng-templates

Tags: angular, ng-template

I have two `<ng-template>`s.
How can i conditionally render one of them without an outer element?

I would like to do sth like this:

`<ng-container
      *ngIf="condition ? ngTemplateOne : ngTemplatetwo">
</ng-container>`

Comment: If with `outer element` you mean the ngTemplateOutelet, you can't. But, in case, you can achieve it this way: `<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="someCondition ? template1 : template2"></ng-container>`

Comment: @JacopoSciampi you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

If with outer element you mean the `ngTemplateOutelet`, you can't. 
But, in case, you can achieve it this way:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="someCondition ? template1 : template2"></ng-container>
```

If you need to pass to those templates an `object` to use, the syntax is different:

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="someCondition ? template1 : template2" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{item:item}">
</ng-container>
```